# Out of Memory issue while using Picasso and Recycler View

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, android-recyclerview

I get this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 15052812 byte allocation with 12653776 free bytes and 12MB until OOM
```

This is my Adapter:

```
public class ExploreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Obj> exploreList;
    private Context context;
    private Typeface typeFace, italicTypeface, boldTypeface;
    private DatabaseHelper db;

    private Obj featureProject;
    private boolean exploreReturned50;



    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView projectTitle;
        public ImageView projectPicture;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            projectTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.exploreProjectTitle);
             projectPicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.exploreProjectPicture);

        }



    }

    private static OnGrabMoreListener mOnGrabMoreListener;

    public interface OnGrabMoreListener {
        void onGrabMore(int position);
    }


    public void setOnGrabMoreListener(OnGrabMoreListener onGrabMoreListener) {
        mOnGrabMoreListener = onGrabMoreListener;
    }

    public class MyFeatureViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView featureProjectTitle;
        public ImageView featureProjectImage;

        public MyFeatureViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            featureProjectImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.featureProjectImage);
            featureProjectTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.featureProjectTitle);
           }


    }

    public ExploreAdapter(Context mContext, Obj featureProj, List<Obj> explores, Typeface myTypeface, Typeface myTypefaceItalic, Typeface myTypefaceBold) {
        context = mContext;
        exploreList = explores;
        typeFace = myTypeface;
        italicTypeface = myTypefaceItalic;
        boldTypeface = myTypefaceBold;
        //to set up grabmore
        if(exploreList.size() == 50 || exploreList.size() == 51) {
            exploreReturned50 = true;
        }
        db = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        featureProject = featureProj;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType){
            case 0:
                return new MyFeatureViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.feature_item, parent, false));  }
         return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                 .inflate(R.layout.explore_item, parent, false));


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        int pos = getItemViewType(position);

        if(pos == 0) {

            MyFeatureViewHolder featureViewHolder = (MyFeatureViewHolder) holder;

           featureViewHolder.featureProjectTitle.setTypeface(boldTypeface);

            featureViewHolder.featureProjectTitle.setText(featureProject.getProjectTitle());


             String createImagePath = Constants.PROJECT_IMAGE + featureProject.getDefaultPicId();
            Picasso.with(context).load(createImagePath).placeholder(R.drawable.default_user).into(featureViewHolder.featureProjectImage);

        } else {

            MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            Obj proj = exploreList.get(position);


            myViewHolder.projectTitle.setTypeface(boldTypeface);


            myViewHolder.projectTitle.setText(proj.getProjectTitle());


            String createImagePath = Constants.PROJECT_IMAGE + proj.getDefaultPicId();
            Picasso.with(context).load(createImagePath).placeholder(R.drawable.default_user).into(myViewHolder.projectPicture);

        }


            mOnGrabMoreListener.onGrabMore(position);
        if (position > (exploreList.size() - 20) && exploreReturned50) {
            grabMoreFromExplorer();
        }

    }

    private void grabMoreFromExplorer() {

        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "GRAB MORE");

        Call<List<ObjResp>> call = ApiManager.getAsyncApi().exploreProjects(exploreList.size());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ObjResp>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<ObjResp>> call, Response<List<ObjResp>> response) {
                    storeInDbNewExplore(response);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<ObjResp>> call, Throwable t) {

                    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "There has been an error retrieving explores project " + t);
                }
            });

    }

    private void storeInDbNewExplore(Response<List<ObjResp>> response) {
        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "STORING explores ");
        List<ObjResp> projectsApi = response.body();

        for(ObjResp proj: projectsApi) {
            String projectId, projectTitle, defaultPicId, isType, isChanged;

            projectId = proj.get_id();
            projectTitle = proj.getTitle();
            defaultPicId = proj.getDefaultPicId();

            isType = 1;
            isChanged = 0;
            Obj newDbExploreProj = new Obj(projectId, projectTitle,  defaultPicId, isChanged, isType);

            db.createProject(newDbExploreProj);
        }
        //TODO sort explores by dateAdded
        List<Obj> newExploreList = db.getProjects(1, 0);
        exploreList.addAll(newExploreList);
    }


    //Plus one for feature project
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

      //  Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "THE EXPLORE LIST SIZE IS "  + exploreList.size() );
        return exploreList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

}
```

This is my Recycler View Call in my activity:

```
exploreAdapter = new ExploreAdapter(this, featureProject, exploreProjectsList, TypeFaceProvider.getTypeFace(this, 0),
                TypeFaceProvider.getTypeFace(this, 1), TypeFaceProvider.getTypeFace(this, 2));
        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);

        //used for setting spotlight item first
        mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                if(exploreAdapter.getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
                    return 2;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }

            }
        });
        exploreRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        exploreRecyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


        exploreRecyclerview.setAdapter(exploreAdapter);
        exploreRecyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerClicks.RecyclerTouchListener(this, exploreRecyclerview, new RecyclerClicks.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                DatabaseProject proj = exploreProjectsList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), proj.getProjectTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                takeToProjectProfile(exploreProjectsList.get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));


        exploreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Out of memory Error in picasso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334644/out-of-memory-error-in-picasso)

Comment: Matei Radu - that leads to people explaining to use different library which does not solve the issue...

Comment: @Lion789 see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CRASH:**

As your stacktrace says:

> "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 15052812 byte
>   allocation with 12653776 free bytes and 12MB until OOM"

you try to display a huge bitmap on your view. Your phone doesn't like it.

**Two solutions:**

- reduce the dimensions of your image, use a smaller image... and
  retry!
- or set `android:largeHeap="true"` in your Manifest, in your application
  tags. It will increase your heap size and avoid the **OutOfMemory**
  error, but your application will probably lag.

Comment: Thanks, I just reduced the size by using resize() to half in Picasso seems to be fine

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update in case someone has a similar problem: replacing Picasso with COIL has solved like magic my OOM issue in a low-capacity smartphone. The memory usage dropped almost 50% in my case. Here's the link FYI: https://github.com/coil-kt/coil

It's worth mentioning that I'm using Kotlin.
Happy coding! ;)